# Scheduling a powershell script for DPM 2010

Tags: powershell, scdpm

I am currently setting up DPM 2010 with my HyperV cluster and have found the following powershell script to automatically add new Cluster VM's

http://blogs.technet.com/b/dpm/archive/2009/12/03/hyper-v-protection-with-dpm-2010-beta-how-to-automatically-protect-new-virtual-machines.aspx

I can get the script to work perfectly from the DPM Management Shell. I am struggling to work out the exact syntax to be able to run it as a batch file that I can run each night using Task Manager. Hoping someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax I use to kick off POwerShell from TaskScheduler is kinda clunky, but it works:

**Program:** C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
**Add arguments:** -nologo -command "Path To PowerShell Script"
**Start In:** [Path of script]

Works for me.

Comment: I tried this and the task runs without error but the scrip doesn't run. I had to change it a little to the following

Program: same as you
Arguments: -nologo -command c:\scripts\AddNewCLusteredVM.ps1 hypervcluster.domain "HyperV Cluster"
Start In: C:\Program Files\Microsoft DPM\DPM\bin